# Having trouble with finding the order of $z = 0$ for $(e^{z^2} - 1 - z^2)\sin^3z$

Tags: complex-analysis

My attempt revolves around trying to represent $(e^{z^2} - 1 - z^2)\sin^3z$ as $f(z) = z^na(z)$ where $a(z)$ is analytic at $z = 0$ and $a(0)\neq 0$.

$$e^{z^2} - 1 - z^2  =  \frac{z^4}{2!} + \frac{z^6}{3!}+ \ldots$$

So, we have

$$\left(\frac{z^4}{2!} + \frac{z^6}{3!}+ \ldots\right)\left(z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - \ldots\right)^3$$

but I'm not seeing how to get this into the form $f(z) = z^na(z)$, assuming it's even possible to do this via this route.

Any tips to help me progress?

Thank you

Comment: You can continue as follows: $$
z^4 \left( {\frac{1}{{2!}} + \frac{{z^2 }}{{3!}} +  \ldots } \right)z^3 \left( {1 - \frac{{z^2 }}{{3!}} + \frac{{z^4 }}{{5!}} -  \ldots } \right)^3  = z^7 \left( {\frac{1}{{2!}} + \frac{{z^2 }}{{3!}} +  \ldots } \right)\left( {1 - \frac{{z^2 }}{{3!}} + \frac{{z^4 }}{{5!}} -  \ldots } \right)^3 
$$

Comment: Factor out $z^7.$ The other factor would be a power series whose constant term is nonzero. [one could find the first few nonconstant powers of $z$ and their coefficients, but (IMO) formulating the pattern in them is not necessary. ]

Comment: @coffeemath How would the other factor be analytic exactly? Without formulating the pattern, how do you know?

Comment: Power series are analytic.

Comment: @hakutingo as indicated it is a power series with nonzero constant term. It converges everywhere since its factors do. It is thus analytic, and also nonzero at $0.$

Comment: @Gary I was following you until you factored out $z^3$ from the right hand bracket to be left with $(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+...)^3$. I also factored out $z^3$ but I'm left with a different bracket, the first few terms of the expanded cubic bracket

Comment: @hakutingo I factor out $z$, it becomes $z^3$ because of the $3$rd power on the whole expression: $$
\left[ {z\left( {1 - \frac{{z^2 }}{{3!}} + \frac{{z^4 }}{{5!}} -  \ldots } \right)} \right]^3  = z^3 \left( {1 - \frac{{z^2 }}{{3!}} + \frac{{z^4 }}{{5!}} -  \ldots } \right)^3 .
$$ You know $(ab)^3=a^3 b^3$. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Order of zero of a function is multiplicative. Since $e^{z^2}-1-z^2$ has zero of order 4 and $\sin^3z$ has zero of order 3, $(e^{z^2}-1-z^2)\sin^3z$ has order 7.

In case you want to know why the order of zero is multiplicative, let $f,g$ be two analytic function having zero at $0$ (WLOG) with order $m,n$. Then we can write $f(z)=z^mf_1(z),g(z)=z^ng_1(z)$ such that $f_1,g_1$ are analytic and are not vanishing at $0$. Then $fg(z)=z^{m+n}f_1g_1(z)$ with $f_1g_1(0)\ne0$. So the order of zero of $fg$ is $m+n$. This idea can be easily generalised to any finite production functions.

Comment: I like this approach but I fear it introduces theorems that I may have to prove in my answer, as we haven't gone over it officially yet